# Determine where pop up window pops up

Tags: javascript, popup

Is it possible to determine where a pop up is spawned in relation to the browser window? e.g. left, right, top, etc. etc.

I know I can set the size, scrollbars etc

I use the following to open the window:

```
javascript:(function(){window.open('http://myurl.com/mypage.html')})()
```

This pop up is spawned from the bookmarks toolbar, therefore a link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the method syntax:

```
var windowObjectReference = window.open(strUrl, strWindowName[, strWindowFeatures]);
```

For position use the `left` and `top` parameters, so it will be something like this:

```
  javascript: (function () {
        window.open('http://myurl.com/mypage.html', 
                    'windowname', 
                    'toolbar=yes,top=10,left=10,width=200,height=200')
    })()
```

The `left`, `top`, `width`, `height` are in pixels.

Look at this link for more info:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.open